# How to found regex match for data validation in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, api

There is two set button set 1A button is used to start the project and set 2A button  is used to shutdown. When clicking on set 2A button, it should be disabled until it matches the regex.  The regex is found

```
<tbody data-label-validation="(start|stop)-(ed|f|m|s|su|t|th|w|wd)-([1-9]|1[0-2])_([0-5][0-9])(?i)(am|pm)-(cst|est|mst|pst)">
```

The regex will found from api. Now api url returns status ok then regex is found else it should say in alert not found. [Note: current i am running api url from local host not from server]

API Url: http://localhost:8080/setlabel/project/instance/oldvalue/newvalue

Here is the code for set button :

```
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
  <button data-name="{{.Name}}" data-zone="{{.Zone | baseUrl}}" data-set-action="start" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sets" id="load" data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Processing">Set</button>
  </div>
```

Here is the javascript code for set button:

```
  <script>

  $('.btn-sets').on('click', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
   $this.button('loading');
    setTimeout(function() {
     $this.button('reset');
      }, 8000);
   });

 </script>
```

Here is the code for label validation:

```
   <tbody data-label-validation="{{labelValidation}}">
   {{range .Instances}}
   <tr>
   <td >{{.Name}}</th>
   <td>{{.Type | baseUrl}}</td>
   <td>{{.Zone | baseUrl}}</td>
   <td>
   {{template "startup.html" .}}
   </td>
   <td>
   {{template "startup.html" .}}
   </td>
   <td>
   <button type="button" class="btn {{.Status | statusButtonClass}} btn-circle" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="{{.Status}}" data-trigger="hover">      
   <!-- <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> -->
   </button>
   </td>
   <td>
   <h6>$0.00</h6>
    </td>
  </tr>
  {{end}}
  </tbody>
```

How to find the set button should be disabled until it matches the regex.  The regex is found

```
<tbody data-label-validation="(start|stop)-(ed|f|m|s|su|t|th|w|wd)-([1-9]|1[0-2])_([0-5][0-9])(?i)(am|pm)-(cst|est|mst|pst)">
```

which values are derived from the selected values by the user.